# How to setup a VPN Server on a VPS for SSH?

Tags: ssh, vpn, vps

I have a Ubuntu 20.04 machine behind a router. I live in an apartment building which provides its own Internet connection. My router reports a different IP address than provided by whatismyip.com. Due to this, I suspect I am behind a NAT.

The effect of this is that I cannot ssh into my linux machine when I'm my laptop is not on the same LAN. It works fine when on the same network. The port forwarding is also active on my router. I have purchased a VPS but I am unable to find instructions on how to configure a Linux VPS to act as a gateway between my desktop computer and my laptop.

Any suggestions on how to setup VPN on my VPS for ssh and VNC purposes? The end goal is to ssh into my linux desktop - not the VPS

Comment: this can be achieved with [Wireguard](https://www.wireguard.com/) (a VPN server/client) that works on all major platforms. A start could be [this](https://serversideup.net/how-to-configure-a-wireguard-windows-10-vpn-client/) or [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-20-04-set-up-wireguard-vpn-server/).